# Transpile ES6 string loaded through a database with "new Function()"

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to import a javascript function written in ES6 that's loaded via a GraphQL database. The point of this is so the function can be edited via a CMS. Eg:

```
const javascript = new Function(decodeURI(data.javascript));
const component = javascript();
```

I'd like to somehow transpile the `data.javascript`

Would it be best to do this on the client side (if so, how?) or Graphcool as a serverless function whenever the record is updated? (if so, how?)

Comment: I would not do it on the client side, but rather store the original user input. This would allow you to re-transpile the function with future versions of your transpiler (e.g. bug fixes or new optimisation) or even drop the transpiler once your environment supports ES6 natively.

Comment: Valid point, didn't think of that. Would need to add a "transpiled" field. I'm using GraphQL so now I just need to figure out how to use babel with their server-side functions